# Is there a MySQL interface that doesn't use PHP?

Tags: gratis, linux, cross-platform, mysql, debian

[phpMyAdmin](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/), [SQL Buddy](http://sqlbuddy.com/), and [Adminer](https://www.adminer.org/) all run on PHP. I'm on a Python Debian server and I'd rather not install PHP. Is there a mySQL interface that doesn't require PHP?

Comment: Are you just wanting a programmatic interface or do you want a full GUI?

Comment: @NickWilde either would be fine though it would be nice if there were a full gui

Comment: So it must be for Python, or it simply must not be for PHP? --- And does it make sense to have both of your questions, MySQL and PostgreSQL, in the same question?

Comment: @unor just not php or ruby or anything that would require me to install a language I don't need. I don't use postgresql as much as mysql but I thought I'd ask about it, maybe I get an answer without asking another question but the main question is about MySQL. Besides some clients like adminer support both databases

Comment: Have you tried [**MySQL Workbench**](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/)? It's a desktop GUI application that connects to a MySQL server on the network, optionally via an SSH tunnel (so your DB doesn't need to listen to anything else than `localhost`). Free, cross-platform.

Comment: @LukasGraf wow! looks so neat! I'm definitely going to try it, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Fischer Please post your second question as a separate question.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt can't do that, the highest rated answer becomes off topic, unethical from me, besides that issue is resolved so it's okay, I don't have questions anymore.

Comment: @Fischer oh right, sorry I didn't see. I guess a mod should take care of this.

Comment: I split the second question to http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/3725/postgresql-ui-that-does-not-require-php-nor-gtk

Comment: What specific platforms should the interface run on besides Debian?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a purely programmatic solution, I'd recommend the Oracle provided [Python-MySQL Connector](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/). It is GPL licensed or you can purchase a different license as well. I have only used it a bit so I can't comment on ease of use for advanced functionality but simple queries work fine and fast.

There is also quite good [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/index.html) including some [examples](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-examples.html) available on the Oracle site.

I have [read](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?50,541648,541648) about a [Python/MySQL GUI](https://github.com/dwbarne/PYLOTDB) - although it does appear to be somewhat focused on plotting it does state that it supports creation and management (as well as analysis). Despite not having (yet) tried it from what I've *read* it looks quite good - and since it is open source and python if it is something close you can relatively easily extend it to do what you need.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/):

- free
- works on Windows/Linux/Mac
- straightforward to install (
- it's a desktop application, not a web interface. No need for PHP.
- syntax highlighting
- auto completion
- SQL documentation on the side
- in addition to the SQL Editor, you can design visually database (usual EER) and administer the database.

SQL Editor:

[image]

Visual Database Design:

[image]

Administration:

[image]

Comment: Be careful if you use replication. We had the issue that if you changed data in MySQL Workbench it somehow bypassed replication. Don't know if it is still an issue but you may want to double check first.

Comment: @2called-chaos Thanks, good to know! (maybe will be my tenth bug report there ;) )

Answer (score 4):

An interface is a rather broad term, but if you are looking to manage your SQL databases with a GUI, [SQuirreL](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/) is the most powerful and versatile option. It's not pretty, but once it's set up, it's one of the best tools out there.

I have used it for Oracle, Microsoft, MySQL and PostgreSQL databases with no issues.

It's a Java application, so it doesn't require GTK or anything else for that matter, and it will work on all platforms.

Alternatively, you can simply use `mysql` and `psql` commands from the command line over SSH. That's as simple as it gets, provided that you don't mind opening a terminal.

Answer (score 3):

I'm developing a [database explorer with a focus on breadth, not depth](https://github.com/dotancohen/squeal). It is written in Python 2, which is likely already installed on your server.

<strike>Right now it won't let you run arbitrary queries , but that is high on the feature list.</strike> ***Squeal now supports running arbitrary SQL queries!***

**Note that the application is in a very early stage of development.** Depending on your perspective, that is good or bad. It likely does not yet support all the features that you need, but I am a very responsive developer and I'll add the features as you need them.

Comment: I like what you do, as long as it's running on linux and as long as linux supports python by default, we should create every server side software using python or lets say a programming language that is there by default like C, at least try to do it if we could, why forcing the server admin to install a language he doesn't need to run some software! great job.

Comment: Thanks. [Here is the feature request for supporting arbitrary SQL statements](https://github.com/dotancohen/squeal/issues/1), if you are interested. I'll try to get it resolved in the coming week.

Comment: I just resolved the issue mentioned above. **Squeal now supports arbitrary SQL statements!**

Answer (score 1):

A tool that is well worth mentioning is [HeidiSQL](http://www.heidisql.com/).  It is really a Windows app but can be made cross platform with other programs like [Wine](http://appdb.winehq.org/appview.php?iAppId=3326).  I use HeidiSQL for the majority of MySQL table queries and MySQL Workbench for the high-level database admnistration.

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend [Database Workbench](http://www.upscene.com/database_workbench/) - although it's a Window based tool, it works fine under Wine and is used by many users like that.

It includes design, debugging, management, migration and database browsing and editing tools.