# PostgreSQL UI that does not require PHP nor GTK

Tags: gui, postgresql

pgadmin requires GTK which I'm not going to install on a server.

Is there PostgreSQL UI that does not require PHP nor GTK?

Free, cross-platform.

(*Split from [Is there a MySQL interface that doesn't use PHP?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/3022/is-there-a-mysql-interface-that-doesnt-use-php)*)

Answer (score 5):

If you want to minimize dependencies on the server, your best bet is sure to be enabling an SSL-only connection over the PostgreSQL protocol from your desktop/laptop. You can then use any software of your choice via the remote network protocol.

If you don't want to expose PostgreSQL to the wider Internet, even SSL-only with a limited range of permitted source IPs, that's OK. You can use an *ssh tunnel* from your laptop/desktop into the server, with *TCP/IP port forwarding*. That way PostgreSQL only needs to listen to the loopback interface.

(BTW, there's really no harm in installing extra client libraries, language runtimes, etc. Disk space is nearly free, and that's the only meaningful resource they use. It makes sense to avoid unnecessary services with listening ports, unnecessary setuid binaries, etc, but a plain old language runtime - it's really harmless).

(from https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/3023/2217)